# Passing/saving to other classes an ID for later use

Tags: c++, mysql, oop

So I'm doing a project in C++ with phpMyAdmin DB's.

It's about a retailer that has multiple stores all over the place.

My menu starts in the headquarters, but the user also has the option to 'jump' to a store in order to store-related stuff (go to cashregister / check employees/...).

This means, that if a user wants to go to a store, it needs to give in the storeID that it want's to go to.

So I have this:

```
cout << "* * * * - S T O R E   M E N U  - * * * *" << endl;
    cout << "Give the store ID you want to go to\n List of known stores:\n";
    cout << "\nStore ID    Store-name " << endl
        << "----------------------------------" << endl;

//this gives a list of the stores that are in the DB:

    vector<Store*> storelist = stores->getAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < storelist.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(8) << storelist.at(i)->getStore_ID() << setw(35) << storelist.at(i)->getStore_name() << setw(6) << endl;

    }

    cout << "\nGive the store ID you would like to go to: ";
    cin >> storeID; cout << "\n";
```

but now I'm not sure in order how to use the storeID, in other classes. Since all of the SQL-queries need to work regarding the storeID.

For example if we look at the menu of the store:

```
1) Go to cashregister
2) View sales
3) View employees
4) Add employees
5) View stock
```

the SQL statements need to automaticly retrieve the value of the storeID that I asked earlier to the user, but will it know the value since I use it in a complete other class?

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: You can use that ID when calling your other class, as a method argument, and then pass as a parameter to the query which that class uses.

Comment: thanks for the comment @Ashalynd, I didn't quite understand your answer tho. I have also recieved an answer from someone else who says that the best thing to do is to make a abstract class where you store the ID in, and let the other menu classes implement it. Isn't this a better way? thanks